# Override PropertyNamingPolicy for specific API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My ASP.Net Core API is using default JSON property naming policy (camel case), but some API calls consumed by external modules expects the API results in Pascal Case.

Is there a way to override the default policy at individual API call level? I mean, only for 1 or 2 calls.

Comment: Why you don't use [`Attribute routing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis)  for 1or 2 calls ?

Comment: @JasonPan How do I specify for some API calls that the result JSON properties should use PascalCase formatting instead of the default camel case?

Comment: Does AlesD's answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible by specifying the `PropertyNamingPolicy` in the `JsonSerializerOptions`. You can do this globally or when you are creating a `JsonResult` object. Since you want this only on specific calls I think the second option is what you are looking for.
Here is the sample code form the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-systemtextjson-based-formatters) for this case.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() =>
    new JsonResult(
        _todoItemStore.GetList(),
        new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = null
        });
```